# XAML markup error when binding List<string> to a ComboBox ItemSource in a WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I'm trying to implement MVVM in a WPF app but am hitting a weird issue where `List<string>` is apparently being treated as a `string` and breaks the XAML designer.

from the XAML:

```xml
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" 
          Grid.Column="1" 
          Name="ServerListComboBox" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Margin="10" 
          Padding="5" 
          ItemsSource="Bind ServerList"/>
```

from the ViewModel:

```
public List<string> ServerList
{
    get { return model.ServerList; }
    set
    {
        model.ServerList = value;
        OnPropertyChange(nameof(ServerList));
    }
}
```

from the model:

```
 public List<string> ServerList { get; set; }
```

The designer says *Invalid Markup* and produces this error:

> Error XDG0028 The TypeConverter for "IEnumerable" does not support
>   converting from a string.

Clearly it's a `List<string>` not a `string` and compilation is fine, but I can't use the XAML Designer anymore. Is there something simple I'm overlooking to make the designer work again? Thanks for any advice, tips, or help

Comment: Ok, is that not how you set the ItemSource to your List<string>? What's the correct way?

Comment: Shouldn't it be like this? `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ServerList}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
ItemsSource="Bind ServerList"
```

to:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ServerList}"
```

Comment: Thanks! That was it.